# Reading large text file using an other file as input format string

Tags: file, matlab, formatted-input

I have large formatted text files ( 200 Mb) containing data that would be useful to read and save easily. The periodicity of the format is of about 72 lines and I would like to have an other file containing a 72 line template format. Is there a way of doing this?

The ideal way would be

```
formatstring = fileread(templatefile)

fileToRead = fopen(LargeFile,'r')

while ~feof(fileToRead)

object{i} = textscan(fileToRead,formatstring)

i = i+1
end
```

The template file would look like :

```
CASE # %16f            DATE: %s

AILERON ANGLE        STAB ANGLE
%4.2f                 %4.2f

ALPHA      BETA     GAMMA

%4.2f      %4.2f      %4.2f
```

Comment: Wait, so you *have* a format file, and want to use it to read your data? Or you have data, and you want to *create* the format file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a format file and transform that into a valid format string, use this:

```
% read format file
fid = fopen('untitled.txt', 'r');
A = textscan(fid, '%s');
fclose(fid);

% transform into proper format string
A = A{1}(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(A{1}, '%')))
A = [A{:}];
```

in that case,

```
>> A
A = 
    %16f%s%4.2f%4.2f%4.2f%4.2f%4.2f
```

which you can use directly in the `textscan` in your `while`-loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. The cellfun function is always very useful.